# Coupling between classes

Tags: oop, coupling

Let's assume we have two classes: `Patient` and `MedicalExamination`. We want to get all examinations for a specific patient. Which one is better:

1. `patient.getExaminations();`
2. `examination.get(patient);`

Comment: I would say...it depends on whats' the **best point of view for this domain**. IMO in this case I would say **#1** because it's an instance method instead of a static one (which I would avoid when possible). Moreover "given a patient get all his examinations" sounds more similar to **normal UI flow**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, an examination **cannot exist** without a patient. Therefore Patient would be the **root entity** of the aggregate **Patient - MedicalExamination**, and as such Patient (or PatientRepository) would be the way to retrieve patient details and examinations:

```
 patient.getExaminations();
```

Answer (score 1):

How would you implement the second way? It would force you to loop over all examinations and see which one are about your patient.

The first method however will allow each patient to hold its own examinations and thus immediately retrieve it. Therefore my preference goes to this method.

Give the object as much information as you reasonably should (without lowering security concerns) so it can operate on its own.

Answer (score 0):

A doctor usually have a file for each patient, in each patient's file, there is a list of medical examination.

So, you get the patient from the doctor office, then you get the examination from the patient's file.

so:

```
patient.getExaminations();
```